# String.replace in javascript for back slash

Tags: javascript, regex

Friends,
This is my String. I need to replace the string with some special characters.

Input:
 `'{"country":["US"],"state":["TX"],"Brands":["brd1"," brd12"]}'`

And Output String should be this: 
`"country"=\'US\',"state"=\'TX\',"Brands"=\'brd1, bd2\'`

I am not able to replace the string with a `'\'` (back slash).

Can anyone help me with the fix?

Regards
Giri

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service and expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1823841). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Post your code. Also try using \\ instead \

Comment: Your input is a JSON string, so parse it out into an object and work with that. You'll find it far more reliable than trying to use magic instead.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It might be that adding those ``\`` is not correct at all. Where you you want to use that output string?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably an xy problem. Either way, here we have a solution:

```js
var str = '{"country":["US"],"state":["TX"],"Brands":["brd1"," brd12", " brd13"]}';

var newStrings = "";

var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var first, mid, last;
first = mid = last = ""

for (k in obj) {
  var pArr = "";
  obj[k].map((o, i) => {
    if (i == 0) first = "'";

    if (i == 0 && i != obj[k].length - 1 || i > 0 && i != obj[k].length - 1) mid = " ,";

    if (i == obj[k].length - 1) last = "'";

    pArr += first + o + mid + last;
    first = "";
    mid = "";
    last = "";
  })

  newStrings += k + "=" + pArr + ","
}

var res = newStrings.replace(/\'/g, "\\'");

console.log(res);//country=\'US\',state=\'TX\',Brands=\'brd1 , brd12 , brd13\',
```